# Laravel cannot create cookie from other function

Tags: laravel, cookies

I have this function

```
    function setAuth(){
            if(Cookie::has('accesstoken')){
                $value = Cookie::get('accesstoken');
                echo 'tokense';
                return $value;
            }
            else{
            echo 'no token';
            $client= new Client(); 
            $response= $client->post('getToken'
            ]);
            $res= json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents()) ;

            Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('accesstoken',$res->access_token,10));

             return $res->access_token;
            }


}
```

If I call this function like http://localhost:8000/setAuth, this can create cookie.
But in Other function I want to use it like this

```
function order(Request $request)
{
    $client= new Client();

    //if get cookie
    $token= $this->setAuth();
}
```

calling order function can't create cookie, Where am I missing.

Comment: Cookies aren't sent until you return a response. Try `return 'ok';` at the end of your `order()` function and you should see a cookie set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queued cookies don't get sent by Laravel until you `return` a response of some kind.

```
function order(Request $request)
{
    $client= new Client();

    //if get cookie
    $token= $this->setAuth();

    // here we go!
    return 'ok';
}
```